# Update Matlab Standalone while executing that standalone

Tags: matlab

I've distributed a working standalone to different users. When they are connected to a share drive I would like to have a check if there is an update available of this standalone.
I've got this working, it will download the new install package to the directory where the standalone is located. However I can not install it as the standalone is already running (your not allowed to overwrite running applications)
Is there any way to make this update go automatically? 
In code:

```
copyfile(name,CurrentDirectory); % Download the new package [this works]
system([CurrentDirectory,name,' -o']); % Can't overwrite the .exe file (this code will just run the package of the standalone)
```

Thanks in advance for the help,

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you try to use some program to update itself. This sounds rather problematic, here is what you can do:

1. Run `mainProgram` to get the package that you need
2. Let `mainProgram` start a second program `updater`
3. Let `updater` kill `mainProgram` and update the program
4. Let `updater` start your `mainProgram` and terminate itself

It will require the programs to have some rights, but I hope it gets the job done for you.

---

Here is a script that I use to kill all Excel instances for your my user. I suppose this can be changed to deal with `mainProgram` instead.

```
    [~, computer] = system('hostname');
    [~, user] = system('whoami');
    [~, alltask] = system(['tasklist /S ', computer, ' /U ', user]);
    excelPID = regexp(alltask, 'EXCEL.EXE\s*(\d+)\s', 'tokens');
    for i = 1 : length(excelPID)
        killPID = cell2mat(excelPID{i});
        system(['taskkill /f /pid ', killPID]);
    end
```

This is what I use under windows, not sure if this works on other OS but it should not be hard to find how to kill a process in other operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I was "afraid" that this was the only solution, as it forces me to make more than one file.
I do have a question about point 3, how can I force to close a program/ script from an other script?

Comment: @user2894107 I have added some code on how to kill a process. If you are not using windows it may not work but it should be quite easy to find an alternative.